# AIR Browser invocation not getting arguments

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flex3

I finally figured out how to launch my AIR native-installer desktop app from a browser, but I'm not getting any of the arguments passed in.

I added this to my native installer app (from http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=app_launch_1.html)

```
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"       
       invoke="onInvoke(event)">
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
import flash.events.InvokeEvent;
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;

public function onInvoke(invokeEvent:InvokeEvent):void {
    var now:String = new Date().toTimeString();
    logEvent("Invoke event received: " + now);

    if (invokeEvent.currentDirectory != null){
        logEvent("Current directory=" + invokeEvent.currentDirectory.nativePath);
    } else {
        logEvent("--no directory information available--");
    }

    if (invokeEvent.arguments.length > 0){
        logEvent("Arguments: " + invokeEvent.arguments.toString());
    } else {
        logEvent("--no arguments--");
    }
}

public function logEvent(entry:String):void {
    log.text += entry + "\n";
    trace(entry);
}
]]>

(etc.)
```

The app is successfully launched from this method

```
        private function onButtonClicked(e:Event):void {
            var APP_ID:String = "my_app";
            var PUB_ID:String = "";
            var ARGS:Array = ["123", "abc"];
            _air.launchApplication( APP_ID,PUB_ID, ARGS );
        }
```

logEvent says the Invoke event was received, but I always get "--no arguments--".

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try launching from the command-line and see if the args  are passed. The only thing i can think is that the browser is (for soem security reason) blocking the args from being passed

Answer (score 1):

Use `BrowserInvokeEvent` instead of `invokeEvent` on application.

Add this in your application complete handler,

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(BrowserInvokeEvent.BROWSER_INVOKE, onBrowserInvoke);
```

Then play around below method on passed arguments from browser launch.

```
protected function onBrowserInvoke(event:BrowserInvokeEvent):void
{
    Alert.show(event.arguments.toString(),"My Args");           
}
```